# In R, how can I reorder the legend of a multi-group time series plot to reflect the end values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hey I'm new at this so please bare with me. I have a time series plot for vaccinations per capita of every county in Pennsylvania and I would like to reorder the legend to reflect the order of the final values for each county. The top piece of code gives me the first plot which is how I want the colors to be, but the legend is in alphabetical order.

The second piece of code and plot put the legend in the right order, but changes the line color order as well. Essentially I want the graph in the first example with the legend order in the second example.

```
COVID_per %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Total_per_capita, col = County.Name)) +
  geom_line()


COVID_per %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Total_per_capita, col = fct_reorder2(County.Name, Date, Total_per_capita))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

[Picture of both graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuCFI.jpg)

Comment: there are so many colors that it's not useful to distinguish them?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `scale_color_discrete()` function.

Original:

```
iris %>% ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = Species)) + geom_line()
```

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CRMn.png)

Reordered legend items

```
iris %>% 
ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = Species)) + 
geom_line() +
scale_color_discrete(
   breaks = levels(fct_reorder2(iris$Species, iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)) # supply your ordered vector here
                     )
```

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6170.png)

You should always include a reproducible example with your question, so it easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick. I'll read up on creating reproducible samples for next time. Cheers!